# Queue_Flush Not flushing Text and speaking updated

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, text-to-speech

I read many blogs but still facing issue with speaking of updated text string after calling shutdown. Next time clicking on play, will speak old string and new one after other. Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.batful);
    try {


        editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit();
        // editor.putBoolean("b", true).apply();
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        value = sharedPreferences.getString("personalmessage", null);
        Log.e("Voice Message create: ", value);


        value = sharedPreferences.getString("personalmessage", null);

        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {
                if (i != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {

                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                       /* textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());*/

                    final Handler h = new Handler();

                    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

                                textToSpeech.speak(value, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);

                            } else {
                                textToSpeech.speak(value, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            }
                            h.postDelayed(this, delay);
                        }
                    }, delay);

                }
            }
        });


        stopvol = (TextView)

                findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stopvol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                turnoffbeep(getApplicationContext());
                finish();
            }
        });
    } catch (
            Exception e)

    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

static void turnoffbeep(Context contextforstat) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Turn Off beep");

    if ((textToSpeech != null)) {
        //    textToSpeech.stop();
        textToSpeech.shutdown();


    }
}
```

If u see QUEUE_FLUSH is added but results are not achieved. Looking at Android documentation, I believe I m following correct. Still If someone help me in looking for correct reason for not dropping old text, pls

Just got other fact if I change input from shared preference to edit text , it is speaking latest text not old.

Answer (score 0):

after R&D got issue, it was handler which are creating mess and picking old text. As shutdown do not cancel handler and replay was adding another handler to existing.